# stl container for table

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any data structure for a table? like storing this:

```
    Width    Height
1     5        10
2     3        20
3     10       2
```

What I need is to address a value by row number and title, e.g. (2, "Height") will give 20.
I know I can do an array of maps or 2d array and a map as column name to number, but is there a ready data structure for this?

Comment: I would map arrays, instead of arraying maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [Boost::MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) yet?  It's almost like an in-memory representation of a database table.  You can query on several rows, a single row, and such.  Very powerful, very useful, and I think it would solve the issue you're asking.

Taken from the boost website:

> Boost.MultiIndex features additional functionalities, like subobject searching, range querying and in-place updating of elements, which make it a convenient replacement for std::set and set::multiset even when no multi-indexing capabilities are needed.

In your case, I'd look at the [composite_key](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/key_extraction.html#composite_key).

Answer (score 6):

Not directly prepared, but the STL is wonderful and you can always combine your way there:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::map<std::string, int> col_val_map;
typedef std::vector<col_val_map> table;

int main(){
  table t(3);

  std::string col = "Width";
  t[0][col] = 5;
  t[1][col] = 3;
  t[2][col] = 10;

  col = "Height";
  t[0][col] = 10;
  t[1][col] = 20;
  t[2][col] = 2;

  col = "Random";
  t[0][col] = 42;
  t[1][col] = 1337;
  t[2][col] = 0;

  std::cout << "\t\tWidth\t\tHeigth\t\tRandom\n";
  for(int i=1; i <= 3; ++i){
    std::cout << i << "\t\t" << t[i-1]["Width"]
                   << "\t\t" << t[i-1]["Height"]
                   << "\t\t" << t[i-1]["Random"]
                   << "\n";
  }
}
```

With output shown on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/VlxIt).

Or, as @DeadMG says, just the other way around:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<int> row_val_array;
typedef std::map<std::string,row_val_array> table;

int main(){
  table t;
  t["Width"].reserve(3);
  t["Width"][0] = 5;
  t["Width"][1] = 3;
  t["Width"][2] = 10;

  t["Height"].reserve(3);
  t["Height"][0] = 10;
  t["Height"][1] = 20;
  t["Height"][2] = 2;

  t["Random"].reserve(3);
  t["Random"][0] = 42;
  t["Random"][1] = 1337;
  t["Random"][2] = 0;      

  std::cout << "\t\tWidth\t\tHeigth\t\tRandom\n";
  for(int i=1; i <= 3; ++i){
    std::cout << i << "\t\t" << t["Width"][i-1]
                   << "\t\t" << t["Height"][i-1]
                   << "\t\t" << t["Random"][i-1]
                   << "\n";
  }
}
```

Again, shown on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/XvFIl).

Comment: Nice solution, problem is that this means a lot of memory allocation for trivial data

Answer (score 4):

An array of structures will do, won't it?

Comment: But it will be redundant, the map can be shared for all them.

Comment: Cold you explain why it'll be redundant? I don't see that.

Answer (score 1):

If your table is sparse (almost empty) then a single `std::map` using an `std::pair<int, std::string>` as key is a good solution.

The only non-trivial algorithm is iterating over a column efficiently (but can be done reasonably using `std::map::lower_bound`).

Answer (score 0):

Not in the C++ Standard Library, I'm afraid. Of course, lots of people have implemented something like this - you can see my own rather simple-minded implementation [here](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/source/browse/alib/inc/a_table.h) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/source/browse/alib/src/a_table.cpp).

Comment: Both of your links link to the same thing

Comment: @Dani Yes - one is the header file and one is the source. I mistakenly posted a link to the header twice. Martinho has fixed it.